# MongoDB: Removing key/value pairs

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document in my collection:

```
{'CArray': [{'count': 0, 'cat': 'nails'},{'count': 0, 'cat': 'screws'}], '_id': 'barrons'}
```

I'm trying to work out a query that will pull a specific array element based on the condition that `count` <= 0.

I have tried the following:

```
update({"_id":"barrons","CArray.cat":"nails"},{"$pull":{"category.cat":{"CArray.$.count": {"$lte": 0}}}})
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i was looking for:

```
update({"_id":"barrons"},{$pull:{CArray:{count:{$lte: 0},cat:"nails"}}})
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
update({"_id":"barrons","CArray.cat":"nails"},{$pull:{CArray:{count:{$lte: 0}}}})
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up doing pretty much the same with: update({"_id":"barrons"},{$pull:{CArray:{count:{$lte: 0},cat:"nails"}}})

Comment: Just wondering will the above erroneously remove the screws too?

Comment: yes, it will remove the screws, as there's no condition on cat. To only remove nails, then you can use the following     
update({"_id":"barrons","CArray.cat":"nails"},{$pull:{CArray:{count:{$lte: 0}, cat:"nails"}}})